# Show that if $f(x)$ is $o(x^3)$, then $f(x+ x^2)$ is $o(x^3)$

Tags: calculus

Here, $o$ is the small-o notation, not to be confused with the big-o notation.

So I am trying to get the $3^\text{rd}$ degree polynomial approximation of the function $f(x) = \cos(x+x^2)$ using various ways and thought that if I can show that if $f(x)$ is $o(x^3)$, then $f(x+ x^2)$ is $o(x^3)$, I can easily get the $3^\text{rd}$ degree polynomial approximation I want.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about $x \to 0$, $f(x)$ is not $o(x^3)$.

Comment: Why not?? $\phantom{?} $

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why not

Comment: Because $\cos(x+x^2)\sim 1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust
Oh yes that is correct. But I was trying to get the linear approximation of $cos(x+x^2)$ like this: $cos(x) - 1 + 1/2x^2 = o(x^3)$ so $cos(x+x^2) = 1 - 1/2(x+x^2)^2 + o(x^3) = 1 - 1/2x^2 - x^3 + o(x^3)$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing this holds in a neighbourhood of $0$, it's very simple with the rules of *Asymptotic Analysis*:

By substitution, we have $f(x+x^2)=o\bigl((x+x^2)^3\bigr)$. Now, $\; x+x^2\sim_0 x$, so that $\;(x+x^2)^3\sim_0 x^3$ and ultimately $\;o\bigl((x+x^2)^3\bigr)=o(x^3)$.

Answer (score 2):

For small $x$,$$f(x+x^2)\in o((x+x^2)^3)=o(x^3)O((1+x)^3)=o(x^3)O(1)=o(x^3).$$This works fine for $f(x):=\cos x-1-\frac12 x^2$. But your problem needs something different. With $\equiv$ denoting equivalence to order $x^3$,$$\cos(x+x^2)\equiv 1-\frac12 x^2(1+x)^2=1-\frac12 x^2-x^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$o((x+x^2)^3)=o(x^3+3x^4+3x^5+x^6)=o(x^3).$$